# Is it alright to connect NC (no internal connection) to the ground?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I understand "NC" means you better "leave it hangin'". However, due to the brimful nature of my boards full of components, and the Kierkegaardian genius who designed this component:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002200D.pdf
[image: package]

that put the GND pin squarely in the middle rather on the side of the component, I now find myself in the position of having no choice but to connect a trough-hole to GND by laying tracks right through the NC pin, since under the component laid several tiny trough-holes already.

So I'm wondering is it OK for me to do that (connect NC to GND)? Since in the datasheet it specifically said:

[image]

But I'm not 100% sure?

Or I could be wrong, there shouldn't be any non-GND via under the power IC, and instead, there should be a patch of GND plane?

Comment: LOL don't you just love English.... good question. By "no internal connection " you could assume do what you want... but "true No Connect" means the opposite.

Comment: So how am I supposed to interpret it? I shouldn't connect it to anything?

Comment: I'd like to say go with the No Internal Connection one and run your trace through there, but I won't. If you have one you can always test it and see if that is a problem just to be sure.

Comment: I'm confused by your PCB description though. Did you not use the recommended land pattern?

Comment: You have several options: 1. Use appropriate board tracing technology to route the part in accord with specifications, making your layout less brimful and more optimal; 2. Send e-mail to Microchip support and ask what is "true no connect" pin and if they approve the connection. 3. You can x-ray the part to determine if there is any bond wire on this particular batch of chips. However, "no internal connection" sounds pretty 100% definitive to me.

Comment: You could edit the component in your PCB CAD and remove the NC pad.  The is no doubt the NC pin is NOT connected to anything.

Comment: I'm more concerned about his other comments. It sounds like he is not using the standard pattern. I hope he realizes that significantly affects the thermal characteristics of his device.

Answer (score 5):

This one is really clear, surprisingly clear in fact ... downright enlightened.   That additional wording that MicroChip put in ... "true ..." makes it a very safe bet that you can perform whatever routing function through that pin you wish to ease your layout.  The only caveat is not to put a sensitive net through the pin, since it will add parasitics (a handful of pF) if it matters.

Alternate wordings would be "DNC" for do not connect, which is a command, not a suggestion.  or "Reserved" where you must fear for your life if you ever connect that pin incorrectly.

I've been reading data sheets since the '70s and they have not been better or worse across time.  This one is very clear.

To convince yourself, put your meter on the highest resistance range to each pin in turn.  Checking that it declares over-range.  Make sure that you perform each measurement with both polarities of the meter.  Most meters use a one-polarity source, often ramping in a triangle, so they read differently each way and a diode will fool you.

Comment: The datasheet is very clear. "No internal connection. The pins marked NC are true “No Connect” pins".  How is that NOT clear????  "it will add parasitics" How will it do that?  No electrons will flow through it.  It's going to add parasitics to Ground?  How? Remember, there is NO INTERNAL CONNECTION, it is not connected to anything.  Nowhere for electrons to go.

Comment: Well ...  No internal connection means that there are no silicon connections to that pin, thus it is great for not hurting the device to connect as you please.  As for parasitics, there are electrons flowing onto the tiny capacitor that the pin creates to the rest of the world.  That parasitic won't upset this application, but if this were high speed or super low current, then it would upset the electrons on the board trace.

Comment: This little parasitic cap, where is it physically? Within the pin between the component body and the SMD pad?   If that is the case then there would be no electrons flowing from the pad up the pin.  It is an open, near infinite resistance/impedance. Not a single electron is going flowing through the pad is going to travel up the pin because there is no energy potential on that pin, zero.  So this pin is sitting on top of a PCB pad, not interfering, not bothering anyone, yet the electrons are going to be upset?  Why?

Comment: So for 30-40 years of reading datasheets, you are saying every time you saw a pin marked NC you thought it may be connected to something?  Really?  Or was that sarcasm.

Comment: @Misunderstood once you start doing high-frequency things, you will find the stray capacitance will become a non-negligible problem. That's what catraeus is talking about. I think it's perfectly plausible to get confused between NC (not connected) vs DNC (do not connect).

Comment: @Misunderstood If you're wondering where the capacitance comes from, have a look at how capacitive touch sensors work. The whole principle behind capacitive touch sensors relies on the effect of parasitic capacitance.

Comment: @Misunderstood FYI, you're right in saying that electrons don't actually flow through but neither do the electrons in a capacitor. Yet, we say that current can flow through a capacitor. It's the same deal here with the NC pin and anything else with a different potential. You can think of the pins as the plates in a capacitor. Although separated, charges can build up on the pins and makes them act like a capacitor. Although the capacitance is small, in high-frequency applications, can be significant.

Comment: I have seen some cases where NC actually was intended to say DNC.  Reading the datasheet (RTFM as they say) you find whether it has no internal connection or is meant to say that it is a must-not-connect.  I double check most everything.  I have designed pacemakers, there is no room for "oh well I'm sure that it actually means ... "

Comment: @Misunderstood on parasitic cap.  It is from the metal surface of the pin ( it can go for a few mm inside the device on bigger chips) to all of the  other circuit conductors that pass nearby. The electric field makes an air capacitor between the pin and other conductors. It is specific to the special cases I indicated.  For example, that pin on this device we've been discussing would shut down DDR4 if it was used as a pass-through route.  It doesn't do diddly to the 2A current that comes from the ground or power connections of this device.

Comment: @tangrs  Electric current flow comes from two means.  One is actual electrons (or protons) that physically move through space.  The other, much more subtle concept, is that electric current flow is due to changing electric fields.  Look up [Displacement Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current)

Comment: @catraeus  I think parasitics was what someone pulled out of their ass here in an attempt to cover their ass when making unsubstantiated statements.  Blame the parasitics, they can't fight back. What you say is true... when it's a pin that has electrons flowing through it. That is not the case here.  Did you have a point?  "would shut down DDR4"  where that came from is beyond comprehension.  The pin cannot be used to pass through to anywhere. If there were a via in its pad the pin could in no way effect any current flowing through the pad or via. You are grasping at straws and failing poorly

Comment: @tangrs I almost banged my head against the wall reading your drivel. You capacitor analogy is as stupid as stupid gets.  A capacitor has two leads with emf energy on both ends.  THIS pin has none.  Touch capacitance has nothing this do with this pin because this pin has no parasitic anything.  A touch sensor has parasitic capacitance which is altered by touch.  Not applicable.  This is not only not a high frequency app, it is not even electrical , it a pin attached to an SMD pad with no meaningful electrical characteristics. Why can you not understand without electron flow there is nothing.

Comment: @tangrs RE: " perfectly plausible to get confused between NC (not connected) vs DNC (do not connect)".  You are confused about a lot of things. But being confused about NC vs. DNC is nothing to be proud of and you might want to consider keeping that to yourself.  It is not plausible to me as is you other ramblings about irrelevant phenomena. Electrons do not flow in a capacitor???  E God.  High frequency???  Irrelevant.  Stay on topic, this is about the pin, not what is floating around in your head.

Comment: @Misunderstood _sigh_ please tone down the ad hominem. I agree this is going off topic and I'm perfectly happy to admit I might be wrong here but please substantiate your arguments with actual sources and evidence. Your last three comments were pure rubbish containing more personal attacks than actual points of discussion.

Comment: @Misunderstood To substantiate my points, I can say that [parasitic capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance) is a well-known real phenomenon. The linked page mentions: "[There] is always non-zero capacitance between any two conductors; this can be significant at higher frequencies with closely spaced conductors, such as wires or printed circuit board traces." 'Any two conductors' can and does include a NC pin on a chip.

Comment: @Misunderstood I'm also perfectly happy to admit that it's plausible to get NC and DNC mixed up. It's all part of the learning process and I don't see anything wrong with it. I tend to find that learning is much easier when you don't have an ego to stroke.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55938/discussion-between-tangrs-and-misunderstood).

Comment: @tangrs I did not say parasitic capacitance is not real, I'm saying it is not applicable in this circumstance. Yes there is capacitance between conductors.   But when there is zero current flowing in the conductors, the capacitance does not matter.  This pin does not have any current flowing through it. And there is only one conductor not two. And enough already about high frequency, there is none of that here either.

Comment: @Misunderstood That's a fair enough point.

Answer (score 0):

NC or 'No connect' usually means 'Not connected', unless the datasheet says otherwise.
DNC or 'DO NOT CONNECT' means do not connect for any reason. (and is could be a factor pin used for manufacturing, or other purposes)